# Finding dupes in MAP data

Tags: apex

Is it possible to find duplicate in the Map

Here is my Map with some data::

```
{
    1=(WrapperTimeCard:[index=1, record=employeeTime:[Id=null,frmhr=1, tohr=3]]),    
    2=(WrapperTimeCard:[index=0, record=employeeTime:[Id=null, frmhr=2, tohr=3]])
}
```

Scenario : I need to find duplicate/overlap number and throw an error if its found, in the above example I have dupes/overlap number `3`

Valid data::

```
{
    1=(WrapperTimeCard:[index=1, record=employeeTime:[Id=null,frmhr=1, tohr=3]]),    
         2=(WrapperTimeCard:[index=0, record=employeeTime:[Id=null, frmhr=4, tohr=5]]),    
         3=(WrapperTimeCard:[index=2, record=employeeTime:[Id=null, frmhr=6, tohr=6]])
}
```

InValid data::

```
{
    1=(WrapperTimeCard:[index=1, record=employeeTime:[Id=null,frmhr=1, tohr=3]]),    
         2=(WrapperTimeCard:[index=0, record=employeeTime:[Id=null, frmhr=2, tohr=3]]),    
         3=(WrapperTimeCard:[index=2, record=employeeTime:[Id=null, frmhr=3, tohr=6]])
}
```

Comment: What sort of user flow is involved? It's unclear whether perhaps `ApexPages.addMessage` might be appropriate here (`Visualforce`) or some sort of `addError` call makes sense/is allowed in context (`Apex Trigger`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be fairly straightforward to just maintain a `Set` of observed values as you loop through:

```
Set<Integer> observedValues = new Set<Integer>();
for (WrapperTimeCard wrapper : myMap.values())
{
    if (observedValues.contains(wrapper.tohr))
        throw new CustomException('Duplicates observed');
    observedValues.add(wrapper.tohr);
}
```

Comment: This won't catch overlaps, though?

Comment: How would it not? First pass on a value, add it to the collection. Second pass (overlap), error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Suppose you have { frmhr: 2, tohr: 5 } and { frmhr: 3, tohr: 4 }. This won't be caught by this technique.

Comment: But he's only trying to deduplicate on `tohr`. Those should *not* be considered overlapping according to my reading of OP.

Comment: Yes, but the OP also said they're time cards. I don't know the last time an employee anywhere was allowed to log overlapping time cards so they can be double-paid.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I never really tried to interpret `tohr` and `fromhr` like that. This does solve the problem statement as it stands (de-duplicate `tohr`), but perhaps the OP needs to be reworded or the original requirements need to be rethought.

Answer (score 2):

I actually did this once by [Using Custom Types in Map Keys and Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm). It's actually pretty clever. Just modify your wrapper class slightly:

```
public class WrapperTimeCard {
    public Boolean equals(Object o) {
        WrapperTimeCard other = (WrapperTimeCard)o;
        return other.frmhr <= tohr && other.tohr >= frmhr;
    }
    public Integer hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }
    // Rest of class
}
```

Then, you can simply add your items one at a time, being sure not to add duplicates:

```
Set<WrapperTimeCard> cards = new Set<WrapperTimeCard>();
for(WrapperTimeCard card: cardList) {
    if(cards.contains(card)) {
        // Duplicate/overlap
    } else {
        cards.add(card);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like `hashCode` could be improved? Also it's kinda nice to cast the comparison wrapper to `that` so you're just comparing `this` and `that` values. :)

Comment: I don't see you call equals method is the contains call that?

Comment: @NickKahn yes, that's the magic behind this process.

Comment: I will give it a shot and thanks for catching up, I like magic behind this process 1+

Comment: @AdrianLarson hashCode doesn't need to be unique when equals returns false, but must return the same value every time when true. So it's easier to just return a single constant.

Comment: But probably slower, no?